# Jupyter notebook hanging due to Django runserver

Tags: django, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Some time ago I made a simple Django application. Recently, I started using Jupyter notebooks for Python and was wondering if I could run my application from such a notebook. To test that, I opened a new notebook and navigated to the top directory of the application:

```
%cd d:\adressen
```

To see if the application could be run from the notebook, I first tried:

```
!py manage.py makemigrations
```

It returned, as it should:

```
No changes detected
```

So far so good. Now starting the server:

```
!py manage.py runserver
```

In a sense nothing happend. No output, the cell label still showing as `In[*]`. Nevertheless, the server was running, for if I opened in my webbrowser the page `http:\\localhost:8000`, my application turned up and all features were working.

I fail to see why in the notebook `makemigrations` is handled correctly and `runserver` makes it hanging. The Jupyter console did not show anything that could have gone wrong.

Having looked at some other questions and answers about Jupyter and Django, I installed `django-extensions` and included it in the installed apps. That did not help. When I start Jupyter with `python manage.py shell_plus --notebook`, open a new notebook and use the same commands, the same happens.

Any suggestions on why this happens and how to overcome it are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At last I think I found what is going on here and how to overcome it.

With the Jupyter shell command `!py manage.py runserver` Django indeed starts the server, but also wants to write to a console. There is no console, so Jupyter seems to hang.

When instead we  use `!start py manage.py runserver`, not only Django starts the server, but also a console opens in which we see the standard Django output when opening a server.

In this way I can use a Jupyter notebook as an IDE for Django projects.